# Bat to run Android_Server from cmd & extra window for port forwarding

Tags: batch-file, cmd, adb

2 Questions, first is most important. 2nd is an issue that im stumped on.

First is a script for Android_Server
second is Android_Server version vs IDA compatibility.

First Question:
my goal is to run a bat file to push android_server to 1 device connected to usb or using wifi adb server on device, then run some commands in adb & dos cmd line while keeping this window open to run the Android_server for IDA. A second window needs to opened! closed after it forwards port. adb forward tcp:23946 tcp:23946 (this is the forwardport.bat)

```
@echo off

adb kill-server

echo [*] Pushing Android Server To Device...
adb push Android_Server /data/local/tmp/
adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/android_server

echo [*]
echo [*] Adding Super User... For Android_Server
adb shell
su

echo [*]
echo [*] Now Starting (Debug Server)...
adb /data/local/tmp/./android_server

start cmd.exe forwardport.bat
Pause
```

my issues are that it dont pause long enough when doing adb shell then su, it starts the server then trys to su, im stuck here so my script fails as im using cmd line & not used to sharing adb & cmd line commands together. what ever creative way this can be made would be awesome.

Second Question:
I know Android_Server is 32bit. using IDA 6.5 64bit I have android_server 1.14 & 1.17
I can only get android_Server 1.14 to work on IDA 6.5 32bit.

If I try to use IDA 6.5 64bit it wont allow me to load either 1.14 or 1.17 so I cant use IDA 6.5 64bit to debug arm processes at all.

Using IDA 64bit: v1.14 does a popup window in IDA says: Warning Incompatible debugging server: protocol version is 14, expected 17

This is what it says when using IDA 64bit switching to v1.17: says nothing on IDA only android_server cmd line window says:

IDA Android 32-bit remote debug server v1.17. Hex-Rays 2004-2013
Listening on port #23946...

Accepting connection from 192.168.0.27
Incompatible IDA version
Closing connection from 192.168.0.27

my goal is to only use IDA 64bit not 32bit. trying to figure out if its the android_server or Android NDK wrong version installed. as I have the full android SDK installed over 20gb Android 1.5-5.0, but only android-ndk-r10b do I need other versions of NDK?

Thanks for any help with either question.